# Python dask groupby apply not working with "processes" scheduler

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, dask

I'm trying to parallelize groupby apply on a pandas dataframe using dask using following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
def dummy_function(df):
    """
    This function doing some python calculations
    and manipulation to given dataframe
    """
    df["new_column"] = df["existing_column"]
    return df
given_df = pd.DataFrame({"Phone_no": ["123", "234", "123", "578"], "City": ["ABC", "BCD", "ABC", "EFG"]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(given_df, npartitions=2)
```

*Working Code*:

```
output_df = ddf.groupby("Phone_no").apply(dummy_function).compute()
```

Even though this code is working but all cores were not being used, after doing some research I found out that as the default compute scheduler of dask is threading so it's due to python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) all cores are not being used. More detail here.
https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Hence I tried to use the "processes" scheduler.

```
output_df = ddf.groupby("Phone_no").apply(dummy_function).compute(scheduler="processes")
```

But this is returning the following error

```
NotImplementedError('object proxy must define __reduce_ex__()')
```

I believe multiprocessing uses pickle in some capacity, hence this error was arising from there.
And the closest related issue I can found is this

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/102#issue-227792648

And one of the comment suggested the following solution

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/102#issuecomment-456528633

**My Question**:

Does the above-mentioned solution works?
And if yes, then how to implement that and where should I make that edit or define __reduce__ex function?

I even tried editing the ObjectProxy class in the wrapt module, but somehow not able to make it work.

Or is there any other way to make the processes scheduler work?

Or make multiprocessing work in any other way than Dask?

Answer (score 1):

You can try seeting up `dask.distributed` in order to submit tasks to the scheduler to be run on workers.

You need to initiate your `dask-scheduler` from the shell.

```
dask-scheduler &
```

Then, choose the number of workers you aim to use with the adress of `dask-scheduler` still from the shell:

```
dask-worker 172.17.0.2:8786 &
```

Then, inside you script , you create `client` instance by passing it IP and port of the scheduler. You can then use this client instance to submit tasks to workers through the `dask-scheduler`.

```
client=Client('localhost:8786')
```

Then, you can compute your results with

```
output_df=client.submit(result)
client.shutdown()
```